# How to concat two columns in source node into one column in target

Tags: symmetricds

Is there any way to concat two column values in source, and copy the result in one column in the target node using SymmetricDS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Shell Script Transformation (bsh). From the [documentation](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_transforms):

> This transformation allows you to provide a Bean Shell script in
>   transform expression and executes the script at the time of
>   transformation

From symmetricds [support discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/739235/thread/9d10e1b5/#eaee):

> If you are using a bash column transform, data for all columns in the
>   row being processed are available. Within your script, the column is
>   available as a pre-defined String variable with the column name. For
>   example, if your row has a NAME column, you can write bean shell code
>   such as return NAME.substring(0,4) to truncate a name to the first
>   four charaters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought that with bsh transformation I only could access to "currentValue" which is the value of the SOURCE_COLUMN in the transformation. So how can I access to more than one column values from the source  with bsh transformation?